# Tesco Hudl adb sideload Gets error "installation aborted"

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, boot-loop, stock-rom

I have a Tesco Hudl HT7S3 which was rooted and i corrupted a file in the system and it is stuck in a bootloop. All i can use is adb sideload.
I found the stock image and have sent it to the device with adb, but when it opens it i get this error:
[image: The Error I Get]

In case you can't see the image, here's what's on my hudl's screen:

```
Recovery system v4.2.41


Now send the package you want to apply
to the device with "adb sideload <filename>"...
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
Installation aborted.
```

Comment: Can you link the source of that stock image as well as instructions you were following? I'm doubting whether the image you got can be sideloaded through recovery.

Comment: @Firelord The link is http://www.modaco.com/forums/topic/365575-stock-hudl-rom-for-rktools-updated-latest-available-rom-20131016200812/ but I can't use rk-tools because it won't pick up my device (my pc is windows 10)